# Session not working in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php

I am passing the session to next page in loop, where i get different values of $post_id, however it seems to take 1 value, and not changing.

```
<?php
include('dataconnect.php');
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
}                   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $post_id = "{$row['id']}"; 
        ?>

        <a href="comment.php?<?php $_SESSION['user_id'] = intVal($post_id);  ?>" >Comment</i></a>

    <?php } 
}  
$conn->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: do you wish to assign different value for session['user_id'] or what?

Comment: You're not echoing anything, so nothing is put into the anchor tag.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a session variable in the URL? The next page can just get it from the session. URL parameters can be faked by the client.

Comment: Setting the session variable in a `while` loop makes no sense. You're just overwriting it every time, and the final value will just be from the last row returned by the query.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do with this code, it makes very little sense.

Comment: you're creating a whole bunch of `Comment` links, I guess they're supposed to have different URL parameters, but there's nothing in the text that distinguishes them.

Comment: Thats very true Barmar. You got it what I am trying to do. I made it work using different approach. However I was trying to set different session values in loop, but it always takes last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **session_start()** function at the beginning of your scripts.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "dataconnect.php";
// do stuff...
?>
```

Comment: I have started the Session already, even if I display session data on next page it displays but it displays same value. no change in value.

Comment: You should use that function in every script (at the beginning) that uses the $_SESSION variable, or use it in dataconnect.php (at the beginning too)

Answer (score 0):

i changed this, hope this help!

```
 <a href="comment.php?session=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] = intVal($post_id);  ?>" >Comment</i></a>
```